# How to include Xcode sub-project headers?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cmake

I'm trying to compile [libcpr](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr) for iOS. I have built cpr using CMake using the Xcode generator. This has generated an `.xcodeproj` I have imported (read drag&drop) into my Xcode project. The problem lies when I try to import the library headers, they are not found:

```
// currently with quote notation but also tried with bracket notation
#import "cpr/cpr.h" // NOT FOUND
```

You can see a more detailed steps on how I built the project in the [respective github issue](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/issues/715).

I can see the subproject contains not only the headers for libcpr, but also for libcurl and zlib (which are also necessary):

[image]

All the information I can find, regarding Xcode and library headers, seems to be some manual steps like copying the header files, which is at the very least prone to errors. Another option seems to be modifying the `User Header Search Paths` property in the build settings. I tried setting the `User Header Search Paths` and `Header Search Paths` to point to the folders:

[image]

I have tried many values in there: `Libraries/**`, `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../cpr/build` (I have added the `libcpr` repo as a submodule, so that's the build output folder) and many other variations. Nothing works.

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/ospfranco/libcprtest) with my current progress. To generate the artifacts:

- Initialize the submodule
- `cd cpr`
- `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -G Xcode -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../ios.toolchain.cmake -DPLATFORM=OS64COMBINED -DENABLE_STRICT_TRY_COMPILE=ON -DDEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.0 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`
- Before compilation you will have to fix an implicit conversion on one header file (cpr/include/body.h just add (int) in the line where the error pops up)
- `cmake --build . --config Release`

That generates the artifact and you should be able to open the `.xcodeworkspace` file in the `iOS` folder from the root repo.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great findings, Oscar!

So, the issue is really Xcode not knowing where to find the header files, and the solution (as you already found out) is simply to use the right search path(s). You have to use `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` (`USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` only works for quote includes).

```
diff --git a/ios/libcprtest.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj b/ios/libcprtest.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
index f16a88c..38d64da 100644
--- a/ios/libcprtest.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
+++ b/ios/libcprtest.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
@@ -599,6 +599,7 @@
                                        "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/boost\"",
                                        "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/Headers/Private/React-Core\"",
                                        "\"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/include/\"",
+                                       "\"$(SRCROOT)/../cpr\"/**",
                                );
                                INFOPLIST_FILE = libcprtest/Info.plist;
                                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
@@ -619,7 +620,7 @@
                                PRODUCT_NAME = libcprtest;
                                SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone";
                                SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0;
-                               USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "Libraries/**";
+                               USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "";
                                VERSIONING_SYSTEM = "apple-generic";
                        };
                        name = Debug;
@@ -672,6 +673,7 @@
                                        "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/boost\"",
                                        "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/Headers/Private/React-Core\"",
                                        "\"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/include/\"",
+                                       "\"$(SRCROOT)/../cpr\"/**",
                                );
                                INFOPLIST_FILE = libcprtest/Info.plist;
                                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
@@ -691,7 +693,7 @@
                                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)";
                                PRODUCT_NAME = libcprtest;
                                SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0;
-                               USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "Libraries/**";
+                               USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "";
                                VERSIONING_SYSTEM = "apple-generic";
                        };
                        name = Release;
```

Alternatively, you could add just the include directories (instead of recursively searching the vendor source / build folder).

```bash
// from repo root
find ./cpr -type d -name include | xargs -I {} echo "\"\$(SRCROOT)/.{}\""
"$(SRCROOT)/../cpr/include"
"$(SRCROOT)/../cpr/build/include"
"$(SRCROOT)/../cpr/build/_deps/curl-src/plan9/include"
"$(SRCROOT)/../cpr/build/_deps/curl-src/include"
```

Cheers!

Comment: omg... I tried so many things! Works perfectly! Thanks a lot Andre!